# How to make a graph network from the following csv

Tags: python, json, api, graph, networkx

I have obtained the following csv from scraping scopus. I want to make a network of authors who are from the same country - like every time two authors are from same country, we add an edge between them.

[This image has the csv file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeeUG.png)

This is the links to complete csv I am using.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B8yaMqFu9yHQudrWI-8-mCpo6pt1T2oW/view?usp=sharing

Also, does anyone know how to find citations data for article['eid] and parse data like:

the following table:

```
author   cited-by author   paper    auth-university     auth-country
```

The idea is to have a network of authors and co-authors, where if each author has a corresponding value in the cited-by author column, an edge is added.

Comment: This is very broad. Have you tried writing any code? What exactly is the implementation problem you need help with, besides writing the entire app? See [ask] and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am new here so may be I made mistake in asking question. But, I think I have a clear point in it - from the csv which I obtained,  how to make a graph between two authors if they meet a certain criteria which is ascertained from the country column. I hope this helps with your understanding about the question. Thanks

Comment: Also, the csv is obtained by writing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an inner join on country to get the edges:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read('/path/to/file.csv')
combinations = pd.merge(data, data, how='inner', on='country')
edges = combinations['author_x', 'author_y']
```

Comment: I can use it to generate a graph of co-authors indeed. But it outputs a very disconnected graph.

Comment: Meanwhile, I am using concat technique and it works too